# Terminologies for moment of inertia

Tags: terminology, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra, moment-of-inertia

Perhaps someone can suggest the right terms for the following mathematical objects related to moment of inertia?

1. A *inertia tensor* $I$. $$I \equiv \begin{bmatrix} I_{1,1} & I_{1,2} & I_{1,3} \\ I_{2,1} & I_{2,2} & I_{2,3} \\ I_{3,1} & I_{3,2} & I_{3,3} \\\end{bmatrix}$$
2. A *product of inertia* is an off-diagonal entry in the tensor: $I_{1,2} = I_{2,1}$, $I_{1,3} = I_{3,1}$, or $I_{2,3} = I_{3,2}$.
3. A *principal moment of inertia* is a diagonal entry in the tensor: $I_{1,1}$, $I_{2,2}$, or $I_{3,3}$. This is the semantic of moment of inertia discussed in elementary treatment of Physics.
4. What is the term for $I_2$ and $I_3$ in the last line below? $$\begin{align*}
             I_{1,1}
             &= \sum_{j} m_j\;\left(r^2_{j,2} + r^2_{j,3}\right) \\
             &= \sum_{j} m_j\,r^2_{j,2} + \sum_{j} m_j\,r^2_{j,3} \\
             I_{1,1} &= I_2 + I_3
           \end{align*}$$

Comment: I have a hard time to see what the question could possibly be. You seem to be asking about the right terminology but the question itself seems to contain the answers.

Comment: I don't know the term for $I_2$ and $I_3$ in number 4.

Comment: The semantic of $I_2$ (or $I_3$) is the perpendicular distance of a mass to $x_2$-axis (or $x_3$-axis) after the position $r$ of the mass has been projected onto the $x_2$$x_3$-plane.

Comment: Mathematically, $I_2 \neq I_{2,2}$ and $I_3 \neq I_{3,3}$ because by definition, $I_{1,1} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,2} + r^2_{j,3}\right)$, $I_{2,2} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,1} + r^2_{j,3}\right)$, and $I_{3,3} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,1} + r^2_{j,2}\right)$, and therefore, $I_{1,1} \neq I_{2,2} + I_{3,3}$.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo You said "The semanatic ... plane". This definition is not conistent because $I_2$ would have dimensions of length. Are you reading any book in particular?

Comment: @jinawee: "The semantic ... after ... projected onto ... plane". Hence, the definition is consistent. The Halliday, Resnick, Walker's Physics, and then, looking around in Wikipedia and HyperPhysics. But, they don't have the name for $I_2$ and $I_3$ in the semantic required by the equation in number 4 when dealing with *any* rigid body.

Comment: The answer to question number 4 seems to be negative: there is not yet any name for $I_2$ and $I_3$ in the semantic required by the equation given in number 4 when dealing with *any* rigid body. So, I propose to call such a mathematical object: "moment of inertia *along* an axis".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A *inertia tensor* $I$. $$I \equiv \begin{bmatrix} I_{1,1} & I_{1,2} & I_{1,3} \\ I_{2,1} & I_{2,2} & I_{2,3} \\ I_{3,1} & I_{3,2} & I_{3,3} \\\end{bmatrix}$$
>     A *product of inertia* is an off-diagonal entry in the tensor: $I_{1,2} = I_{2,1}$, $I_{1,3} = I_{3,1}$, or $I_{2,3} = I_{3,2}$.

True.

> A *principal moment of inertia* is a diagonal entry in the tensor: $I_{1,1}$, $I_{2,2}$, or $I_{3,3}$. This is the semantic of moment of inertia discussed in elementary treatment of Physics.

This is not true, the principal moments of inertia are the diagonal elements (eigenvalues), only if you have diagonalized the inertia matrix (which you can always do).

> What is the term for $I_2$ and $I_3$ in the last line below?
>    $$I_{1,1} = I_2 + I_3 $$

If $ I_{2}=I_{2,2}$ and  $ I_{3}=I_{3,3}$, once you have diagonalized $I$. In general, we have (dropping the indices):

$$I = m \begin{bmatrix}y^2+z^2 & I_{1,2} & I_{1,3} \\ I_{2,1} & x^2+z^2  & I_{2,3} \\ I_{3,1} & I_{3,2} & x^2+y^2\\\end{bmatrix}$$

But in a planar body one of the coordinates is zero, in the example below (continuos body but same concept), $y=0$. Then you can see that:

$$I = \int d\mathbf{m} \begin{bmatrix}z^2 & I_{1,2} & I_{1,3} \\ I_{2,1} & x^2+z^2  & I_{2,3} \\ I_{3,1} & I_{3,2} & x^2\\\end{bmatrix}$$

So the moment of inertia associated to the z axis is the sum of the other two.

[image]

Comment: Is there any term for a diagonal element in an inertia tensor when the matrix is not yet diagonalized?

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo By term do you mean expression? Do you know how to calculate eigenvalues?

Comment: No, I mean the terminology. When I communicate with someone else and I need to say the noun for a diagonal element in the moment of inertia tensor matrix that is not yet diagonalized, what is the noun?

Comment: $I_2 \neq I_{2,2}$ and $I_3 \neq I_{3,3}$ because by definition, $I_{1,1} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,2} + r^2_{j,3}\right)$, $I_{2,2} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,1} + r^2_{j,3}\right)$, and $I_{3,3} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,1} + r^2_{j,2}\right)$, and therefore, $I_{1,1} \neq I_{2,2} + I_{3,3}$.

Comment: That is why I ask whether there is any name for $I_2$ and $I_3$ because they are not equal to $I_{2,2}$ and $I_{3,3}$, respectively. $I_{2,2}$ and $I_{3,3}$ are called moments of inertia about an axis.

Comment: I just realized the answer to "any term for a diagonal element in an inertia tensor when the matrix is not yet diagonalized?" The answer is "moment of inertia about an axis". Now, what is the terminology for $I_2$ and $I_3$ in number 4?

Comment: Perhaps @TadeusPrastowo wants the words "moments of inertia about principle axes" for $I_2$ and $I_3$?

Comment: @ChrisWhite: moments of inertia about principle axes are $I_{2,2}$ and $I_{3,3}$. But, $I_{2,2} \neq I_2$ and $I_{3,3} \neq I_3$. So, I think $I_2$ and $I_3$ should be given another name. I would like to know if the name already exists.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo I think that $I_1=I_2+I_3$ holds only for symmetric bodies, let me check.

Comment: Only holds for planar rigid bodies where $I_2$ is equal to $I_{2,2}$, not rigid bodies with volumes. But, that is beside the point. Is there any name for $I_2$ (or $I_3$) for rigid bodies in general including one with volumes?

Comment: This answer gives additional information w.r.t. to question number 3. And, the answer to question number 4 seems to be negative: there is not yet any name for $I_2$ and $I_3$ in the semantic required by the equation given in number 4 when dealing with *any* rigid body. So, I propose to call such a mathematical object: "moment of inertia *along* an axis".

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo The thing is, that in general $I_{1,1}$ is not the sum of the other two momenta. But that doesn't mean $I_2\neq I_{2,2}$.

Comment: @jinawee: I second that. But like I said, that is beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

They are just the equation above rewritten to a shorter format using the definition of the [moment of inertia about an axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Calculating_moment_of_inertia_about_an_axis):

$$
I = \sum_{i=1}^N{m_ir_i^2}.
$$

The equation above uses $r_{j,2}$ and $r_{j,3}$, which correspond to $I_2$ and $I_3$.

Comment: But, $I_2$ (or $I_3$) is not a perpendicular distance to $x_2$-axis (or $x_3$-axis) while the Wikipedia article defines $r$ in the "moment of inertia about an axis" to be the perpendicular distance of a mass to an axis. The semantic of $I_2$ is the perpendicular distance of a mass to  $x_2$-axis after the position of the mass has been projected onto the $x_2$$x_3$-plane.

Comment: Mathematically, $I_2 \neq I_{2,2}$ and $I_3 \neq I_{3,3}$ because by definition, $I_{1,1} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,2} + r^2_{j,3}\right)$, $I_{2,2} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,1} + r^2_{j,3}\right)$, and $I_{3,3} = \sum_j m_j\,\left(r^2_{j,1} + r^2_{j,2}\right)$, and therefore, $I_{1,1} \neq I_{2,2} + I_{3,3}$.